# Insertando Imagen usando mPDF desde un Input File

Tags: php, mpdf

le vengo dando seguimiento a este tema desde hace un par de semanas.

Tengo un formulario que al ser llenado y presionar Submit, se crea un documento PDF usando la libreria mPDF, aqui no hay ningun problema, sin embargo quiero agregar un Input File desde donde yo pueda subir una imagen y esa misma imagen insertarla en mi documento PDF.

He visto muchos foros en php.net y aqui mismo en SOes y SOen, sigo sin encontrar una respuesta para esta consulta.

Mi **index.php** es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>StackOver</title>
</head>
<body>
                        <div class="container">
                            <h3>Form</h3><br>

                            <form class="nobottommargin" method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="generar.php"  novalidate>
                            
                                <label for="">Ingrese un nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="sm-form-control "><br>

                                <label for="foto">subir imagen</label><br>
                                <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" class="sm-form-control "> <br><br>

                                <button class="btn btn-primary nomargin" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
                                
                            </form>

                        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi archivo **generar.php** es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//Variable donde escribiremos nuestro documento HTML
$data='';

$nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);

//instancia de nuestra clase para crear PDF
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

//escribo mi documento HTML
$data .='<h3>'.$nombre.'</h3>';

//carpeta temporal para almacenar imagenes
$uploads_dir = 'img/';

//Si se quiere subir una imagen
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Recogemos el archivo enviado por el formulario
    $archivo = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    //Si el archivo contiene algo y es diferente de vacio
    if (isset($archivo) && $archivo != "") {
       //Obtenemos algunos datos necesarios sobre el archivo
       $tipo = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
       $tamano = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
       $temp = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
       //Se comprueba si el archivo a cargar es correcto observando su extensión y tamaño
      if (!((strpos($tipo, "gif") || strpos($tipo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo, "jpg") || strpos($tipo, "png")) && ($tamano < 2000000))) {
         echo '<div><b>Error. La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.<br/>
         - Se permiten archivos .gif, .jpg, .png. y de 200 kb como máximo.</b></div>';
      }
      else {
         //Si la imagen es correcta en tamaño y tipo
         //Se intenta subir al servidor
         if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploads_dir/$archivo)) {
             //Cambiamos los permisos del archivo a 777 para poder modificarlo posteriormente
             chmod('img/'.$archivo, 0777);
             //Mostramos el mensaje de que se ha subido co éxito
             echo '<div><b>Se ha subido correctamente la imagen.</b></div>';
             
             //Escribimos la imagen subida
             $data .= '<div align="center"><img src="img/'.$archivo.'" alt="foto" width="242" height="100"></div>';
         }
         else {
            //Si no se ha podido subir la imagen, mostramos un mensaje de error
            echo '<div><b>Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.</b></div>';
         }
       }
    }
 }

$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Los resultados mostrados son los siguientes>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos que pueden ayudar a entender mejor:

1. Archivo **php.init** tiene esta linea> upload_tmp_dir="C:/xampp/htdocs/pdfCreator/img"
2. La estructura de mis carpetas es esta:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Algunos articulos que he revisado:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php

https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/upload-de-imagenes-con-php/?unapproved=304191&moderation-hash=754b0620657778a753e696316e7acb26#comment-304191

Agradeceria la ayuda de alguien con esto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes varios errores. A simple vista, esto `if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploads_dir/$archivo))` debería mostrarte un mensaje de error o crear la imagen como `NAN` por no encerrar entre comillas `"$uploads_dir/$archivo"`. Cuando creas la etiqueta de imagen solo envías el nombre de archivo, sin la ruta y creo que mPDF requiere la ruta absoluta para poder acceder a los archivos.

Comment: Otro error es que estás enviando salida a pantalla con mensajes de error / éxito y después envías el PDF. Puede funcionar en servidores donde tienes habilitado un búfer de salida, de lo contrario, recibirás errores del tipo `Cannot modify header information... Headers already sent...`

Comment: @Triby tu primer respuesta me ha ayudado a entender mejor el problema, podrías publicarla como respuesta? Gracias y [RESUELTO]

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas casi siempre termina cerrada por _errores tipográficos_, de hecho, voy a sugerir que se cierre, por lo que no es conveniente agregar una respuesta. Lo importante es que pudiste solucionar el problema.